# При восстановлении свернутого приложения, из бд выводится только последняя строка

Tags: android, activity, sqlite, android-layout-inflater

В бд есть несколько строк.
Вывожу их "добавлением" layout'a в основной layout таким методом:

```
Cursor q = sql.query(...);
q.moveToPosition(-1);
while (q.moveToNext()) {
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lin_info, Ll, false);
    ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(q.getString(0));
    ....addView(layout);
}
```

Все нормально и правильно выводится. Но, если свернуть приложение или выключить экран и вернуться к нему через полчаса, во всех добавленных layout'ах будет только последнее значение из бд.
Если свернуть и развернуть быстро (даже спустя 10 минут), все данные останутся, но если долго подождать, то будет только последнее значение.

Если выводить данные немного другим способом, без добавления layout'a и использования LayoutInflater'a

```
while (q.moveToNext()) {
    TextView t = new TextView(context);
    t.setText(q.getString(0));
    ....addView(t);
}
```

То такого эффекта нет.
Подскажите, из-за чего это происходит и как этого избежать?

Comment: Такой подход чем-то обусловлен? Почему не использовать обычные адаптеры?

Comment: @Artem, да в принципе ничем, просто интересуюсь. Адаптеры по сути же делаются так же, с помощью inflater'а...